# Word always shows markup/comments automatically when opening a document, even after saving it with "No Markup"

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

Office Word automatically opens this comment section whenever I open the file, until I select No Markup in the section that says Simple Markup.
But it is annoying to have to do this every time I open a file. How can I prevent the comment section on the right side of the file with the red square from opening automatically every time I open the file.
I want this section to open when I want it to open, not automatically.

Answer (score 1):

This is the default behaviour so that you don't forget that there is markup in a document. If you want to change that default behaviour, do the following:

1. Go to "File" > "Options" and in the left sidebar menu open the "Trust Center" tab.
2. Click on "Trust Center Settings" and in the new window, switch to the "Privacy Options" tab in the left sidebar menu.
3. Uncheck the box which says "Make hidden markup visible when opening or saving"
4. Save the options, go to the "Review" tab, select "No markup" and save the document.

When you now reopen the document, the previously saved markup ("No markup") will be loaded.

Comment: when I asked about it, they showed me this way: https://www.elevenforum.com/t/microsoft-office-word-pro-plus-2024-always-opens-the-review-section-automatically.20204/

But I think what you said is a much better solution. It worked. Well, thank you very much. I think you are an authorized person:) I have another question. When I copy text from another program to Excel, it does not preserve the properties of the text, such as being bold or italic. It pastes it as a plain text. Is there any way to save the text to excel with these features, whether bold or italic?

Comment: @timucinpusat glad I could help! If this answer solved your initial question, please make sure to mark it as the correct answer, so that it doesn't appear as "open" for other helpers out there. As for the other question, you should start a separate thread and include as many details as you can (e.g. which program are you copying from, does it work if you try it with a different program, etc.).